# How can you steal the SINS core in Syntax Error?

Tags: payday-3

One of the heist specific challenges for Syntax Error is to steal the SINS core. However, even when the core is completely shut down in loud, it's still protected by a dome of bulletproof glass. How can I steal the SINS core?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4eNI6psACd4), you need two players to each press a button at the same time, with the buttons being located in two spots:

1. On the base of the core container around the back side:

[image: On the base of the core container around the back side.]

2. On a shelf in the office where the basement code was:

[image: On a shelf in the office where the basement code was]

The video later says that this can't be done while playing solo.  So you'll need at least two players.